# In spring jpa, Is there a method to detect optional params for query?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

Suppose I have a search form with 3 fields(first/last/email). The search would search for for records with first/last/email if the param exist.

I could do something like this:

```
if (email & first & last) useMethodThatSearchFistLastEmail
else if (email & first)
else if (email & last)
else if (first & last)
else if (first)
else if (last)
else if (email)
```

but that's just bad.

I could also use native query and append where clause.

Is there a way to do this in JPA?

Comment: I guess you can use the [`CriteriaBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html).

Comment: ugh, of course.. how did i forget this;;; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quick solution using predicates:

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<UserEntity> cq = cb.createQuery(UserEntity.class);
Root<UserEntity> root = cq.from(UserEntity.class);
List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(email)) {
    predicateList.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("email")), email.toLowerCase() + "%"));
}
query = this.em.createQuery(cq.where(cb.or((Predicate[])predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[0]))));
```

note the 'new predicate[0]'. predicate[]::new doesnt work.